# Role permission C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want put a role permission in this link:

```html
    @model IEnumerable<SoftIdeiaFinalProject.Models.DB.Module>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>


<p> 
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "CreateModule", "Account")
</p>
```

All authenticated users of my app can go to this page, but i want that the user that  "IsCLient"(a true or false field of my DB), is true can see this link.... What can i do?

Comment: You would have to pass that value to the view, either through a viewmodel or a viewbag, and use an if statement within your razor view to toggle the link.

Comment: You should also post your controllers action code.